# Find the values $a$, $b$ and $c$ for parabola through point $(1,1)$ and gradient $7$ at point $(3,3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, conic-sections

So I've been able to get here so far:

$$Let\space f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$
$$f '(x) = 2ax + b$$

$$f(1) = a + b + c = 1 $$
$$f(3) = 9a + 3b + c = 3$$

$$f '(3) = 6a + b = 7 $$

I don't understand how to find $a$, $b$ and $c$. I've seen the answers: $a = 3, b = -11, c = 9$. I just don't understand how to get there, given that there are three unknowns.

Comment: Three linear equations with three unknowns. Solve it by substitution. You mean $f(3)=3$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format posts on this site.

Comment: Here’s a start: notice that $9a+3b+c = 8a+2b+(a+b+c)$. Substituting for what you have will make this a system with two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: There is an infinite number of such parabolas. You’re also making the unstated assumption that its axis is vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Simultaneous equations:
$$a + b + c = 1 $$
We want to get rid of one of the variables so that we can have 2 instead of 3 unknowns. I'll look at $a$. Multiply by $9$, to match the $a$ coefficient:
$$9a + 9b + 9c = 9$$
Now you can subtract $f(2)$:
$$9a + 3b + c = 3$$

$$9a + 9b + 9c - (9a + 3b + c) = 9 - 3$$
$$6b + 8c = 6 \tag 1$$

Do the same for $f(1)$ and $f '(3)$, but multiply $f(1)$ by $6$ to match the coefficient of $a$:
$$6a + 6b + 6c = 6$$
$$6a + b = 7 $$
Subtracting:
$$6a + 6b + 6c - (6a + b) = 6-7$$
$$5b+6c=-1 \tag 2$$

Now you have 2 equations with 2 unknowns: $6b + 8c = 6$ and $5b+6c=-1$
Solve these for $b$ and $c$ and then you can solve for $a$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

We have three unknowns and three equations. Therefore, we can solve [the system of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations):
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b+c=1\\
9a+3b+c=3\\
6a+b=7
\end{cases}
$$

We find $a=3$, $b=-11$ and $c=9$.

Answer (score 0):

-$\begin{align}{9a+3b+c =3\\\underline{( a+b+c)=\;\;1}
} \\\underline{8a+2b=\quad 2}\end{align}$

$8a+2b=2\quad 4a+b=1\\
6a+b-(4a+b)=7-1\\
2a=6\\a=3\\
\mathrm{And\; so \;on}$